# Am i testing for a PHP $_SESSION variable too soon after setting it?

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I have a login that I've implemented with AJAX and the PHP on the backend sets $_SESSION['guest'] before sending the response text back. Then it the javascript on the front end redirects me to the guest page which checks whether or not isset($_SESSION['guest']), but often this results in false, and i'm taken to another page (using my else branch).

I'm wondering if maybe I'm checking for it too early and that's why isset($_SESSION['guest']) results in false. But I make it count down 5 seconds before redirecting to the page that tests for it, so this is what I don't understand.

After it happens a couple of times (i logout and log back in again), it stops failing and I can't get it to fail which obviously doesn't help! Thought that may be a caching/cookie problem but I've cleared all that and it still won't fail again.

Any ideas?

```
//this is the login script snippet    
if($rows == 1){
          $_SESSION[$type] = $username; //$type is posted over as guest or client. this is valid right?
          $_SESSION[$type.'_id'] = $result['id'];
          echo $_SESSION['welcome'] = 'You have logged in successfully.';
    }


<?php

//snippet from the guest page. session_start() is invoked within the included 'page_top.php'
    include('page_top.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['guest'])){
        if(isset($_GET['sect'])){
            if($_GET['sect'] == 'photography'){
                include('view_album.php');
            }
            else{
                include('404.html');
            }
        }
        else{
            include('welcome.php');
        }
    }
    else{
        include('403.html'); //i get redirected here!
    }

    include('page_bottom.php');

?>
```

edit: i now think that when it fails the session variable just isn't getting set because if i reload my guest page, it results in the 403.html page every time, so it's not a delay, it just doesnt get set.

Comment: no I've deduced that as as i give it 5 secs after logging it and it still doesn't work, it must just not be setting the variable every time. and i don't think it's a caching issue because that would more likely lead to being logged in accidentally when you return, but it always fails to log me in at the start of my visit

Comment: Could it possibly because I'm setting the session variable's key using $type instead of a string directly such as 'client' or 'guest'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be echo-ing a variable as you are setting it? That doesn't make any sense to me.

```
echo $_SESSION['welcome'] = 'You have logged in successfully.';
```

If $type is being posted over as guest or client, shouldn't it be `$_SESSION[$_POST['type']];`
or are you setting $type to the POST variable somewhere else in the page?

Comment: The result of the expression you quote is that `$_SESSION['welcome']` becomes the string `'You have logged in successfully.'` and then that string is echoed. The return value of the `=` operator is the right-hand value, the value assigned with (and the new value of the variable assigned to).

Comment: I know WHAT it does, I just don't know WHY someone would do that.

Comment: do you mean this bit `echo $_SESSION['welcome'] = 'You have logged in successfully.';` ? i'm pretty sure it's fine to do. either way it's done after the troublesome one is set. It was just shorthand

Comment: And yes I'm setting $type earlier in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You must include this at the top of the page (before ANY HTML or whitepace output, and after the < ?php):

```
session_start();
```

EDIT:

I know this is an old post. But for anyone that needs it in the future here it is!